# PyTorch: Sigmoid of weights?

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm new to neural networks/PyTorch. I'm trying to make a net that takes in a vector `x`, first layer is `h_j = w_j^T * x + b_j`, output is `max_j{h_j}`. The only thing is that I want the `w_j` to be restricted between 0 and 1, by having `w_j = S(k*a_j)`, where S is the sigmoid function, `k` is some constant, and `a_j` are the actual weight variables (`w_j` is just a function of `a_j`). How do I do this in PyTorch? I can't just use a `torch.nn.Linear` layer, there has to be something else/additional to add in the sigmoid function on the weights?

Side question, for that last output layer, can I just use `torch.max` to get the max of the previous layer's outputs? Does that behave nicely, or is there some `torch.nn.Max` or some pooling stuff that I don't understand that needs to happen?

Thanks!

Comment: I am pretty confused - the layers output can be put through a sigmoid or any monotonic function that varies between 0 and 1. This is called an activation function, and there are a various set of functions that you can call (though I am not familiar with pytorch but I am almost positive that this will be built in - see [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/nn/modules/activation.html)) - the last layer output can be put through a softmax function which is essentially a weighted exponential with the sum.

Comment: Softmax is what I was looking for (for the side question)! For the first part, the thing is that I don't want to put the layers output through the sigmoid, only the weight variables, which will then be used in the linear layer.

Comment: Why would you want the weights between 0 and 1? Thats usually not how it works as far as I know

Comment: @DavidMontgomery I was just about to comment something similar. Unless we are looking at some sort of regularisation process as per reg regression etc.

Comment: @Chinny84 It would also alter backpropagation so you'd have to think about that too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am really not sure why would you do that but you can declare a custom layer as below to apply sigmoid to weights.

```
class NewLayer(nn.Module): 
    def __init__ (self, input_size, output_size): 
        super().__init__() 
        self.W = nn.Parameter(torch.zeros(input_size, output_size)) 
        # kaiming initialization (use any other if you like)
        self.W = nn.init.kaiming_normal_(self.W) 
        self.b = nn.Parameter(torch.ones(output_size)) 
    def forward(self, x): 
        # applying sigmoid to weights and getting results 
        ret = torch.addmm(self.b, x, torch.sigmoid(self.W)) 
        return ret
```

Once you do this, you can use this as you would use linear layer in your code.

Comment: thank you! I'm using the sigmoid to ensure the weights are between 0 and 1 - they represent something like items being distributed between people, and each item cannot be distributed more than once or less than 0 times.

Comment: @AWhite If this answer suits your need.. do accept it ;)